# Saving HTML as a PDF, content is displaced

Tags: html, pdf

Today for the first time I decided to create some official documents using plain old HTML, however with the first draft of one of these documents saving as PDF preview shows that content is getting displaced and I preferably don't want to add a load of `<br>` tags in order to space content appropriately...

[image]

Apologies for the blurred out sections, but unfortunately they do contain confidential information.

As you see the Qualifications sections drags on into another page and the layout I'm looking for needs all the Qualifications to be on the second page.

Anybody got any idea's of how to achieve this layout?
Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a page-break-before: always in you css file, in a print specific media query, targeting your title.

[CSS for print](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)